# ngIf doesn't accept function includes of javascript

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a dynamic menu in angular.  I have an array of item roles allowed to see the item.  This is the code for the item menu.

```
  <a  #itemMenu
    mat-list-item
    [routerLink]="item.path"
    routerLinkActive="active-list-item"
    (click)="onItemSelected(item)"
    *ngIf="item.role.includes(currentRole)">
    <mat-icon mat-list-icon class="material-icons-outlined">{{ item.iconName }}</mat-icon>
    <span>{{ item.displayName }}</span>
</a>
```

I don't know why the validation in *ngIf is not valid:

```
 *ngIf="item.role.includes(currentRole)"
```

Appear the next error:

error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

6     *ngIf="item.role.includes(currentRole)">
~~~~~~~~
If I put this validation out of ngIf doesn't generate error. So, I think this code not wrong at all.  My question is what happens with the ngIf?

```
<span>{{item.role.includes(currentRole)}}</span>
```

Comment: This is because TS is not able to determine the expected structure of the item object and hence it throws an error because it could be the async value that's coming from API response. what is the structure of the `item` object? can you try putting `*ngIf="item?.role?.includes(currentRole)"` and see if it works?

Comment: Try `*ngIf="item.role!.includes(currentRole)"` which basically says "item.role is defined, leave me be". Otherwise try `*ngIf="item.role && item.role.includes(currentRole)"`

Comment: Yes, that was it.  I tried *ngIf="item.role!.includes(currentRole)" and worked.  Thanks.

Comment: The solutions aside, binding a function (that too a iterating function like `includes`) to directives and interpolations would trigger the function for each change detection cycle if you're using default change detection strategy. It might lead to performance issues down the road.

Comment: I don't know how to validate if a role is in array when the menuitems are dynamic.  What do you suggest ? For that I thought in the includes function.